# Jasper studio expression editor dialog doesn't open in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

Expression editor dialog does not open in Jasper studio eclipse plugin 6.20.

There is no error log.

Eclipse is Mars.1. Is there a fix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please check if xtext plugin for eclipse is installed. if not try installing xtext plugin. we also faced this problem and we could resolve it after installing xtext.

Comment: It might be useful for future readers to know where to get xtext from, for e.g.: https://eclipse.org/Xtext/download.html